# What is meant by 'Invoke the operating system from user program'?

Tags: exception, mips

I'm reading through my computer organization textbook and have come across a list of events/exceptions, one of them says "Invoke the operating system from user program". What exactly does this mean?

Does this refer to a system call?

Comment: Some more context for that phrase, please…?

Comment: It was in a book called 'Computer Organization and Design' in a table of exceptions and interrupts. There wasn't a whole lot of context given.

Comment: Processor-generated exceptions and interrupts are handled by the OS kernel.  Most important side-effect is that execution mode changes to privileged mode.  So yes, they do get used to make system calls as well, benefiting from the same side-effect.  Googling "int 0x80 syscall" gives relevant hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **INVOKE** directive enables a statement in a program to be processed by the operating system as if it were entered as a command from the terminal. It provides access to most operating system utilities and facilities.

[Taken from this link](https://manual.pvxplus.com/PXPLUS/directives/invoke.htm)

As it says in the link above, Use the INVOKE directive to have the operating system treat a character string from a program as an operating system command from the terminal.

Therefore, in your case, it means getting the attention of the OS from the user program using certain programming techniques.